# extremely SLOW Nginx download over ssl

Tags: php, ssl, curl, nginx

i have this vhost

```
    server {
server_name admin.ex.com ;
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;
##SSL
#listen 443 ssl ;
  listen               *:443 ssl http2 ;
  listen               [::]:443 ssl http2 ;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

#ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384$
ssl_ciphers   EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/admin.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/admin.key;

root /var/www/admin/public/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
access_log /var/www/admin/admin.log;
auth_basic "Top Secret";
auth_basic_user_file /var/www/admin/.htpasswd;


        location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
allow 192.168.1.1;
#deny all;

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.admin.sock;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}

}


}
```

its SO SLOW over HTTPS , i tried to visit phpmyadmin and my own php code over http it loads in 2 secs with HTTPS it takes 2-3 minutes , it loads the HTML code it self fast , but to download the resources (CSS-images) it takes so much time , i'm using chrome with the Nginx 1.9 and a self signed certificate . 
i even tried curl -i  both the HTTP and HTTPS , again so much latency between the two , i don't understand what's going on !

UPDATE :: 
okay after some researching i figured out that if i take an image of exactly the same VPS and applied it to one which is in a server closer to me (Frankfurt instead of NY ) that it gets way faster . is it a distance problem then ? 
What makes me think again is that why when i use HTTP it's so fast no matter what server it is in .

Any ideas ?

Comment: Check you config on SSLLabs.com. And the CHACHA20 ciphers aren't supported by default OpenSSL so have you a special build for this or are those ciphers not being used (again SSLLabs.com report will show this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a location-related problem. I changed the location of the server from New York to Amsterdam which seems to solve the problem.

I understand that a server can be far and thus reduce the connection speed but I don't understand why it reduces the speed under HTTPS only and not HTTP requests. Kind of weird!